# Could not able to replace \" with " in html tags using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to replace a  as  using C#. I could not able to achive this using Regex.Replace functions as follos

Regex.Replace(html, "\\"", "\"");

execution this command again produces the original output

Anyone have already faced issue like this,Any help would be of greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ganesan

Comment: try  `"\\\\""` , the first `"\\"` will be interpreted by the regex engine. or do `@"\\"""`

Comment: Hi x3rf41, can u pls explain in a little detail ..

Comment: sorry, i had a mistake, use `"\\\""` as regex, and t should work, i and writing a detailed answer right now

Comment: all my comments are WRONG, sorry, read my answer :D

Comment: Hi peter, it also does n't woks

Comment: in my answer, both the Regex.Replace i wrote at the end work for me, i just tried it, ignore the comments, as i said, they are all wrong, sorry for that. if it still doesnt work, give example strings and what you want as output

Answer (score -1):

first of all `"\\""`produces a compiler error, since you are just escaping one backslash but not the quote.

you are working with 2 escape mechanisms here, one is from the c# compiler, and another is from the regex interpreter.

Which means:

when you give this C# string as a regex: `"\\\""` then after compilation there is a string looking like that `\"`, which is then interpreted by the regex engine, which also uses `\` as the escape character. therefor regex will escape `"`, so your code will replace `"` with `"`

so if you now use `"\\\\\""`, first the c# compiler will make `\\"` out of that, then the regex engine will make `\"` out of that (both are using `\` as escape character)

now c# has a nice little feature to make such strings easier to write.

if you add an `@` before your string, `\` will no long be the escape character, but now you have to escape `"` with `""`

that means `"\\\""` == `@"\"""` and `"\\\\\""` == `@"\\"""`

so you could write `Regex.Replace(html,@"\\""","\"")`
which is easier to read then `Regex.Replace(html,"\\\\\","\"")`

i think i got it right this time :D

Comment: Hi Peter, not working this Iwant to replace \" format with just a double quotes " i.e "<html lan\"=en\") with  "<html lan="en">"

Comment: `Regex.Replace(html,@"\\""","\"")` does exaclty that! btw, are u inspecting the string with the visual studio debugger? because that adds backslashes into the strings when u go over them

Comment: yes you are right, I was confused it since the hyperlink is not working. the same page which I was loaded in desktop browser works properly with hyperlinks, but the hyperlink is broken in testing with the windows phone 8 device.

Comment: yes you are right, I was confused it since the hyperlink is not working. the same page which I was loaded in desktop browser works properly with hyperlinks, but the hyperlink is broken in testing with the windows phone 8 device. Do any one have faced issues like this before, 

Regards,
Ganesan